# SQL Trying to flatten out data

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a query that I have a SQL pivot in.  My data looks like this

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.[MKEY] ORDER BY es.[FDATE]) as 'Row', FDATE
    PIVOT(
    SUM(s.[EARNINGS])   
    FOR s.[row] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4] ))AS i






Person   |   FDATE| 1      | 2     | 3     | 4
Sam Smith|   2001 | 200.00 | Null  | Null  | Null
Sam Smith|   2002 | Null   | 400.00| Null  | Null
Sam Smith|   2003 | Null   | Null  | 500.00| Null
```

I'd like to have it like this

```
Person    |  FDATE| 1      |FDATE| 2    |FDATE| 3     |FDATE| 4
Sam Smith | 2001 | 200.00 | 2002 |400.00| 2003| 500.00|NULL| NULL
```

What's the best way of achieving this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what was the original table structure you were looking at?looks like you have pivoted it and trying to unpivot on that.what you need can be done from the main table itself

Comment: I've updated the question with my actual code. As you can see I'm looking for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select
     Person
    ,max(case when coalesce(FDATE,0)=2001 then FDATE else 0 end) as FDATE_1
    ,sum(case when coalesce(FDATE,0)=2001 then Earnings else 0 end) as [1]
    ,max(case when coalesce(FDATE,0)=2002 then FDATE else 0 end) as FDATE_2
    ,sum(case when coalesce(FDATE,0)=2002 then Earnings else 0 end) as [2]
    ,max(case when coalesce(FDATE,0)=2003 then FDATE else 0 end) as FDATE_3
    ,sum(case when coalesce(FDATE,0)=2003 then Earnings else 0 end) as [3]
    ,max(case when coalesce(FDATE,0)=2004 then FDATE else 0 end) as FDATE_4
    ,sum(case when coalesce(FDATE,0)=2004 then Earnings else 0 end) as [4]
from <table>
group by
     Person
```

Note that columns you don't actually ask for in the SELECT clause can never appear in the result.

Comment: I'm working on applying your method.  I'll try tonight.

Comment: Thanks.  I managed to get it to work.  After playing around with it I was getting a datatype error.  After playing around a bit I was able to get it to work.